# want to search last space of the line and split it after finding the space in perl

Tags: perl, split, space

Input:

```
<--TD: 2. Set inputs 'i_open1' = "0" and 'i_open2' = "0" and i_cntrl_pwr_down>
```

I want to check for last space of the line and split it from last space.

**Expected output**:

```
<--TD: 2. Set inputs 'i_open1' = "0" and 'i_open2' = "0" and
 i_cntrl_pwr_down >
```

How can I do that in Perl?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I edited your question, but I am not sure if I got it right. Please review the edit

Answer (score 0):

The question is a tad unintelligible. Expected output adds an extra space before the >, which I think is just a misprint. This is my suggestion anyway:

```
my $str=q(<--TD: 2. Set inputs 'i_open1' = "0" and 'i_open2' = "0" and i_cntrl_pwr_down>);
$str =~ s/(.*) /$1\n /;
print $str;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#@59bqaBSXFKkYKtQqGGjqxviYqVgpKcQnFqikJlXUFpSrKCeGZ9fkJpnqA5UomSgpJCYlwITM0IWy4xPzispyokvKC@KT8kvz7PTtOYCmWxbV6yvoaelqaCvYhiTp6BvzVVQlJlXArbV@v9/AA)

Answer (score -1):

i am simply count total no of character .

$str_len = length($line3);
   if($str_len > 72){}
then i am simply  searching for last  charcter ending with d and space and chacter starting with i (d i)
if((@split_line = ~/[\s+.]+|_$/) and @split_line=~ /\d$|^ i/ ){
n then unpacking it

but its not a correct way to do it .

Comment: Please add this info to your question and delete this answer. Answers should not be used for comments